# React Native expo - keyboard

Tags: react-native, expo

i created app (React Native) everything good, but when i open my keyboard, All elements of the application, such as images and titles, rise to the top, i can't explain it without images..

Normal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAo7u.jpg)

When I open the keyboard
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fFPs.jpg)

How can I avoid and solve the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.